# Error: request for member begin which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

*I am trying to create a code to read a binary file in a vector and then copy the content of the vector multiple times.*

For that purpose I am using a istreambuf vector to initialize it. And then using the std::copy function to copy it to a ostream object.

```
//#include headers...
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream input("some/file/", ifstream::binary);
    ofstream output;
    vector<char> buffer (istream_iterator<char>(input), istream_iterator<char>( ));
    for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        string file_name = "/some/name";
        output.open (file_name.c_str(), ofstream::binary);
        copy( buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(output));
        output.close();
    }
}
```

However the compiler renders the error:

> > request for member 'begin' in 'buffer', which is of non-class type 'std::vector(std::istream_iterator, std::istream_iterator (*)())

How do I fix this? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: [Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). `buffer` is not a variable of type `vector<char>`, it's a function returning `vector<char>` and taking a pair of parameters. If your compiler is sufficiently modern, use braced initialization: `vector<char> buffer{istream_iterator...};`

Comment: [Wow, Clang's so handy.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c9b3261d75ae2b6)

Comment: It works now that I've put parentheses around it! Thanks!